# Getting the subheaders in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, multi-index

I'm currently using openpyxl to use an excel file that has mul-indices (2 Levels of headers) and i'm trying to do the operations depending on the subheaders a header has.
I have some exp. doing this in pandas but for this Project i have to use openpyxl which i barly made any use of before.
Only thing i could think off is the manual way:

- iterating over the rows
- saving the first row as header and 2nd row as subheader
- do some cleaning.
- manually save the headers with their subheaders in dics. then filleing in the values by iterating over all the cols

my code is as follows:

```
#reading the excel file
path = r'path to file'
wb = load_workbook(path) #loading the excel table
ws = wb.active #grab the active worksheet


#Setting the doc Header
for h in ws.iter_rows(max_row = 1, values_only = True): #getting the first row (Headers) in the table
    header = list(h)

for sh in ws.iter_rows(min_row = 1 ,max_row = 2, values_only = True):
    sub_header = list(sh)

#removing all of the none Values
header = list(filter(None, header))
sub_header = list(filter(None, sub_header))

print(header)
print(sub_header)
#creating a list of all the Columns in the excel file
col_list = []

for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row=3,min_col = 1): #Iteration over every single row starting from the third row since first two are the headers
    col = [cell.value for cell in col] #Creating a list from each row
    col = list(filter(None, col)) #removing the none values from each row
    col_list.append(col) #creating a list of all rows (starting from the 3d one)
#print (col_list)
```

But i'm sure there must be a better way that i wasnt able to find in the docs or by checking this website.

Thanks in advance!

My goal in the end is to automate this part of my code by iterating over the header and use the subheaders of that head and their values each time
code:

```
#bulding the templates using yattag "yattag.org"
doc , tag , text = Doc().tagtext()

#building the tags of the xml file
with tag("Data"): #root tag
    for row in row_list :
        with tag("Row"):
            with tag("Input"):
                with tag(header[0].replace(' ','_').replace('\n','_')):
                    text("In " + dic[row[0]]+" the precentage of Students " + " regarding the "  + header[0] + " the Precentage of Students with "+ sub_header[0] + " is "+ str(row[1]) + " whereas the " + sub_header[1] + " are " +   str(row[2]) )
                    with tag("Row_Data"):
                        text(dic[row[0]] + " | "  + header[0] + " | " + sub_header[0]+ " | " + str(row[1]) + " | " + sub_header[1] + " | " + str(row[2]))
                with tag(header[1].replace(' ','_').replace('\n','_')):
                    text("In " + dic[row[0]]+" the precentage of Students " + " regarding the "  + header[1] + " the Precentage of Students with "+ sub_header[2] + " is "+ str(row[3]) + " whereas the " + sub_header[3] + " are " +   str(row[4]) )
                    with tag("Row_Data"):
                        text(dic[row[0]] + " | "  + header[1] + " | " + sub_header[2]+ " | " + str(row[3]) + " | " + sub_header[3] + " | " + str(row[4]))
                with tag(header[2].replace(' ','_').replace('\n','_')):
                    text("In " + dic[row[0]]+" the precentage of Students " + " regarding the "  + header[2] + " the Precentage of Students with "+ sub_header[4] + " is "+ str(row[5]) + " whereas the " + sub_header[5] + " are " +   str(row[6]) )
                    with tag("Row_Data"):
                        text(dic[row[0]] + " | "  + header[2] + " | " + sub_header[4]+ " | " + str(row[5]) + " | " + sub_header[5] + " | " + str(row[6]))  
                with tag(header[3].replace(' ','_').replace('\n','_')):
                    text("In " + dic[row[0]]+" the precentage of Students " + " regarding the "  + header[3] + " the Precentage of Students with "+ sub_header[6] + " is "+ str(row[7]) + " whereas the " + sub_header[7] + " are " +   str(row[8]) +" and for " + sub_header[8] + str(row[9]) )
                    with tag("Row_Data"):
                        text(dic[row[0]] + " | "  + header[3] + " | " + sub_header[6]+ " | " + str(row[7]) + " | " + sub_header[7] + " | " + str(row[8]) + " | " + sub_header[8] + " | " + str(row[9]))
                with tag(header[4].replace(' ','_').replace('\n','_')):
                    text("In " + dic[row[0]]+" the precentage of Students " + " regarding the "  + header[4] + " the Precentage of Students with "+ sub_header[9] + " is "+ str(row[10]) + " whereas the " + sub_header[10] + " are " +   str(row[11]) )
                    with tag("Row_Data"):
                        text(dic[row[0]] + " | "  + header[4] + " | " + sub_header[9]+ " | " + str(row[10]) + " | " + sub_header[10] + " | " + str(row[11]))  
                with tag(header[5].replace(' ','_').replace('\n','_')):
                    text("In " + dic[row[0]]+" the precentage of Students " + " regarding the "  + header[5] + " the Precentage of Students with "+ sub_header[11] + " is "+ str(row[12]) + " whereas the " + sub_header[12] + " are " +   str(row[13]) )
                    with tag("Row_Data"):
                        text(dic[row[0]] + " | "  + header[5] + " | " + sub_header[11]+ " | " + str(row[12]) + " | " + sub_header[12] + " | " + str(row[13]))  
                with tag(header[6].replace(' ','_').replace('\n','_')):
                    text("In " + dic[row[0]]+" the precentage of Students " + " regarding the "  + header[6] + " the Precentage of Students with "+ sub_header[13] + " is "+ str(row[14]) + " whereas the " + sub_header[14] + " are " +   str(row[15]) )
                    with tag("Row_Data"):
                        text(dic[row[0]] + " | "  + header[6] + " | " + sub_header[13]+ " | " + str(row[14]) + " | " + sub_header[14] + " | " + str(row[15]))  
            
#print(doc.getvalue())
result = indent(
    doc.getvalue(),
    indentation='   ',
    indent_text=True
)

#saving the xml file
with open("output.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Comment: Are you_ sure you have to use `openpyxl` directly? `Pandas.read_excel` reads excel files. (calling internally `openpyxl`).

Comment: yeah that's exactly my problem, i do have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless Pandas is completely off the table I think you might be able to do something pandas and openpyxl. The documentation mentions reading data from openpyxl into a pandas dataframe: [Working with Pandas and Numpy](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html).
Could you use:

```
data = ws.values
df = DataFrame(data[2:,:], index=data[0], columns=data[1])
```

There may be some filtering necessary with regards to the `None` values.